# What is the best way to create a logger file in Node js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, logging

I found two ways to create a logger file in the Node js project.

1. We can create a local logs file that can store every log for the specified expiration time.

```
var errLog = `Error :${title} \n ${text} \n \n TimeStamp : ${new Date()} \n ============================== \n\n`;
let dateString = new Date().toISOString();
this.fs.appendFile(`logs/${dateString.split('T')[0]}_error.log`, errLog, function (err) {});
```

This is how I am using a local logger to store logs.

2. Another way is to store all logs in the database with expiration time. It can store some specific details like size, data, status, etc. for each and every log.

If there were any other better ways then please share them.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, packages such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston already provide multiple logging solutions which you can explore. For instance, I use winston with datalust-seq

Comment: Yes @SomeoneSpecial you were right, if we want to use the default way to store logs we can use [Wilston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) package. But here I need to generate different log files for every single day. And also after n(any number of days) number of data I want to delete it.